# Jasperreports over.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT..) not working

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdfstamper

**Goal:** Stamp text in PDF counting pixels from the right. Basically looking for `over.setTextMatrix(x, y)` from the right.

**Problem:** `over.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT...` does not seem to work (see screenshot).

[image]

```
public void stampTextPDF(PdfContentByte over) throws JRScriptletException, SQLException {
        
        String text = "TEST2TEST2";
        
        over.beginText();
        over.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);
        over.setRGBColorFill(127, 129, 147);
        
        /* Shows text right, left or center aligned with rotation.
         * @param alignment the alignment can be ALIGN_CENTER, ALIGN_RIGHT or ALIGN_LEFT
         * @param text the text to show
         * @param x the x pivot position
         * @param y the y pivot position
         * @param rotation the rotation to be applied in degrees counterclockwise
         */
        over.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, "Test!!!TEST2", 22, 5, 0);


        //over.setTextMatrix(780, 15);
        //over.showText(text);
        over.endText();
}
```

My environment is Jasper-Reports 6.5.1 (yes it's old) and following:

```
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfGState;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
```